# How to download database log files from AWS RDS for today's date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

when I open RDS logs section, it is showing 1000 entries for a single day.
How to download complete logs by filtering only today using AWS cli.

This [link](https://www.howtodojo.com/get-and-analyze-aws-rds-for-postgresql-logs/) downloads all the logs but how to filter only today's logs?

Comment: [Publishing PostgreSQL logs to CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html#USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.PublishtoCloudWatchLogs) is an option for you ? If yes, then there was several ways you can get logs from CloudWatch, based on automation needs and related filter criteria. Just note, that when you enable these logs exports, it takes your RDS instances resources such as CPU and memory during export process execution.

Comment: Cloudwatch again requires more cost. Anyway to get this through cli itself?

Comment: uday-kiran - Is [python, boto3](https://github.com/awslabs/rds-support-tools/tree/master/database-logs/move-rds-logs-to-s3) based solution to put logs on AWS S3, option for you?

Comment: yeah that is good, can you guide steps for this. thanks you very much

Comment: Amazon s3 I have created a bucket and set cloudwatch.Logs are being generated for audit and trace. But with s3, able to share individual file download links only. Any option to set complete bucket /folder to public and users can access that? I tried updating bucket policy but no use.